# No Content matches the given query. (Django)

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I am trying to complete a 'Hackernews clone tutorial (Django Unchained by Tuts+) so I can get my head around using Django as I am a noob. 
However I am currently stuck on creating the points/vote system. Instead of the votes being applied to a specific peice of content I am getting a 404 error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/vote/
No Content matches the given query.
```

here is my code.

**Voting in views.py**

```
def vote(request):
  content = get_object_or_404(Content, pk=request.POST.get('content'))
  content.points += 1
  content.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**urls.py (inside of 'collection')**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'collection.views.index'),
    url(r'^content/$', 'collection.views.content'),
    url(r'^vote/$', 'collection.views.vote'),
)
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load content_extras %}

{% block head %}
    <script src='{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}'></script>
    <script src='{% static 'js/vote.js' %}'></script>
{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}

    <ol>
        {% for content in contents %}
        <li>
            <p>
                <a href='/vote/' id='content-vote-{{ content.id }}'>+rep</a>
                <a href='{{ content.url }}' id='content-title-{{ content.id }}'>{{ content.title }}</a><span class="domain">({{ content.domain }})</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                {{ content.points }}points by {{ content.moderator.username }}{{ content.created_at|age }}
            </p>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endblock %}
```

**AJAX**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function vote(content){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/vote/',
        data: {'content': contentID},
        success: function(){
            $("#content-vote-" + contentID).hide():
            $("#content-title-" + contentID).css({'margin-left:'15px});

        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$('a.vote').click(function(){
    var contentID = parseInt(this.id.split('-')[2]):
    return vote(contentID);
})

});
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps try removing quotes from `'collection.views.index'`. It is hard to say what exactly the problem is but I am pretty sure it is within `urls.py` file. Maybe change `vote` function for now and see whether you can access it directly. If yes, then the next problem is going to your function

Comment: Removing the quotes from the url `'collection.views.index'` returns another error. However if I remove the body of the function from vote and just return a `HttpResponseRedirect('/')` or `HttpResponse('vote')`  it redirects properly or displays 'vote', so I am thinking it must be a problem with the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the error suggest that you were doing `GET` request:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/vote/
```

I think this is because in your `index.html`, you are using:

```
<a href='/vote/' id='content-vote-{{ content.id }}'>+rep</a>
```

And you try to bind `onClick` on it using:

```
$('a.vote').click(function(){
    var contentID = parseInt(this.id.split('-')[2]):
    return vote(contentID);
})
```

This `$('a.vote')` selector won't work, since there is no `<a>` that has `class="vote"`. Thus, the `onClick` thing is not working, either. You are directly hitting `/vote/` using `GET`. Hence the error.

Comment: `<a href='/vote/' id='content-vote-{{ content.id }}' class='vote'><img src='{% static 'images/arrow.gif' %}'></a>` updated the code to this. I am still seeing the same error

Maybe I misread your response and did not implement what you intended me to?

Comment: Can you please open the developer tools in your browser? You will sure some error in the Javascript console.

Comment: You need to make sure the selector actually works before doing anything else. In this case, using class selector will results in an array. You need to use `$('a.vote')[0]` to get the correct element.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` This is what I am seeing in dev-tools

Comment: Just remember to solve as many visible error as you can, before asking a question on SO. And always turn on the dev-tools.